# How to load a JS file in my HTML doc?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm using codecademy to teach myself to code and am trying to load a JS file in an HTML doc. Obviously I cannot find info in google searches to help me understand what I'm doing wrong. This is my current HTML to have the JS file load. Can anyone help me understand what I'm doing wrong so I can have the .js file run when this the HTML file loads? According to the standards at codecademy, the JS file itself is written properly.

```
<body>
    <h4 id="header">...Games...</h4>
    <h2 id="list">pick from our unique selection of brand new games...</h2>
    <script src="Cards.js"></script>
</body>
```

Comment: Are both files in the same directory? Any error messages on the console?

Comment: if you load the script like that, the file Cards.JS needs to be in the same folder as this html script.

Comment: yep, all files are in the same directory, that's why I'm confused as to why it's not working.

Answer (score 1):

That should load fine, as along as your index.html and Cards.js files are in the same folder. If you put your Cards.js file in a /js/ folder, you will need to add /js/Cards.js to your path.

As a side note, I recommend downloading Firefox and the Web Developer and Firebug addons. It will show you if your files are loading and if they're generating any errors, and where the errors are located in the file.

Comment: A lot of browsers are now including developer consoles, but I do love firebug.

Comment: That's why I'm confused, they are definitely both in the same folder.

Comment: Do you possibly have an error somewhere else in your code that's preventing any further JS from functioning? Is the site hosted somewhere that I can check out?

Answer (score 0):

Your script tag is supposed to be in the  part of your html document. Make shure the file.js is in the same folder as your file.html or include the folder in the src-attribute as mentioned above.

Your code should loke like this, if you want your script to affect the whole page:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stylesheet.css"/>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="file.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    #Your page tags
</body>
</html>
```

Hope this solved your problem! :-)

Comment: I wish it had. Still nothing... :(

Comment: You mentioned that you're using codecademy to learn coding, do you use the web-editor of codecademy to write your code or do you code locally? If you happen to use the web-editor, I suggest you start coding on your computer locally since you'll have the full control over things! If you code online this might have provoked you're problem, because you cannot diversify wether it's an issue of the codecademy server or you wrongly coding if things don't go the way they should! Good luck and go on coding, started learning to code on codecademy too!

Answer (score 0):

- The html text you posted above should have a name (index.html or games.html) make sure the file type is .html
- Make a folder on your computer, give it a name and put your saved html file in that folder. That folder is now your root or directory folder.
- Add the javascript file "Cards.js" to the folder next to your html file.
- In your text editor open those two files (index.html, Cards.js).
- Run the html file in a browser, the "Cards.js" should load. Good luck, hope this helps.

Comment: all these I have already done, which is why I'm confused about the error.